# Absolute positioned element in a relative flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a div with `display:flex` and `position:relative`.
I'd like to have an overlay element on the bottom of this div so I put `position:absolute` on it. If its height would be auto that would be the best but not must have. The problem is if I scroll the parent relative div then the absolute positioned goes with it. How could I pin it to the bottom?
[Code](http://codepen.io/apreg/pen/mAzKxN)

I'd like a pure css solution.

**Update1:**
A working solution: http://codepen.io/apreg/pen/gwBdJq

Comment: Your problem isn't exactly the most clear, nor is the code you've provided, however it sounds like you may be looking for `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`?

Comment: As a sidenote, please note that `//` line comments are not legal in CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I 'm aware of that but got used to the preprocessors and such where it is handled.

Answer (score 0):

If I got what you want, you always want to have arrows on the screen. But that's fixed position then, like this:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAzjWE

```
.actionRow {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:120px;
}
```

Comment: Close but the problem with fixed is that if you hide the masterCell then the arrows stay fixed. I want them to go to the very bottom when the masterCell is hidden.

Comment: Your js solution is what I want to achieve indeed but without js.

Comment: Can't be done in CSS with this HTML5 code, you should move masterCell next to buttons to get it with target pseudo class

Comment: Could you present your idea please? The structure is not carved in stone. If it behaves and looks like like I described then it is probably ok.